# jmeter webdriver sampler is not running when the test is run thru jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Jmeter - Selenium webdriver sampler is not running when the JMeter Test is run thru Jenkins job, but the Selenium Webdriver sampler is running fine when running the test from JMeter instance. Anyone has solution for this issue.

Comment: Both of the above scenarios were run from the same client machine (thru JMeter instance directly and thru Jenkins job).

Comment: The issue is fixed after changing the chromedriver.exe path relative to Jenkins Workspace path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment :

The fix was to change [chromedriver.exe](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) path and make it relative to Jenkins Workspace path.